# jQuery Slider How do I lock a handle in place?

Tags: jquery, slider, handle, slide

I have a jQuery slider with a two handles.  I'm looking to lock the first in place based on the second handle.

I've tried checking the values on the *slide* event and then setting the first handle back to it's lock position but it basically ignores what I set it to and continues to slide.

I have gotten it to work with the *stop* event but its very clunky.

I'm using a JSON object generated from the serverside to populate my sliders.  This is my code for the stop event:

```
   $(clientID).slider({
        range: true,
        max: slider.max,
        values: [slider.minVal, slider.maxVal],
        change: afterSliderChanged,
        stop: onSliderStop
    });

    function onSliderStop(event, ui) {
    for (i in sliders.sliders) {
        var slider = sliders.sliders[i];
        var clientID = slider.cellType + "_" + slider.objectID + "_null";

        if (this.id == clientID) {
            if (ui.values[0].toString() == slider.max.toString()) {
                var values = $(this).slider('option', 'values');
                $(this).slider('option', 'values', [parseInt(slider.max - 1), parseInt(values[1])]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Let me know if I need to elaborate.

Thanks!
Daniel Brewer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick and dirty example of how to lock the other handle in relation to the handle that is being dragged:

```
var offset = 40;
$('#slider').slider({
    range: true,
    max: 600,
    values: [40, 80],
    slide: function(e,ui){
        if (ui.value == ui.values[0]) {
            $(this).slider('values',1, ui.value+offset);
        } else {
            $(this).slider('values',0, ui.value-offset);
        }
    }
});
```

Should help you figure out how to do what you are wanting to do.

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/cBHdD/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly less quick-n-dirty version of @PetersenDidit's jsfiddle, that locks handles in relation to each other and also clamps the offset between them at the ends of the sliders, so the range can't collapse below `maxOff`.  The key is `return false`, to keep jquery-ui from applying the current drag value:

```
var max = 600;
var maxOff = 40;

$('#slider').slider({
    range: true,
    max: max,
    values: [40, 80],
    slide: function(e,ui){
        if (ui.value == ui.values[0]) {
            $(this).slider( 'values', 1, ui.value+maxOff);
            if (ui.value >= max - maxOff) {
                $(this).slider( 'values', 0, max - maxOff);
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $(this).slider( 'values',0, ui.value-maxOff);
            if (ui.value <= maxOff) {
                $(this).slider( 'values', 1, maxOff);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tbWE5/